# Internal Drive Changes Letter on Boot

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, drive-letter

I'm running Windows 7 x64 and every time I boot my machine it changes the letter of one of my drives. I have four drives and this is the only one that ever does this. Any ideas?

Comment: You have provided insufficient information for us to help you. Explain your hardware configuration, including drive type, BIOS settings, and so on, and we may be more forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning it a specific letter? There's a walk-through here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Change-add-or-remove-a-drive-letter